# Proper line-break formatting according to PEP 8?

Tags: python, formatting, pep8

According to PEP 8, this is acceptable (and what I have used in the past):

```
result = some_function_that_takes_arguments(
    'a', 'b', 'c',
    'd', 'e', 'f',
)
```

My question is, does this also apply to the function definition, so something like:

```
def some_function_that_takes_arguments(
    a, b, c,
    d, e, f,
):
    return a,b,c,d,e,f
```

Another example of what I have done in the past:

```
if (this_is_one_thing
    and that_is_another_thing
):
    do_something()
```

I've been doing it this way for a while (for consistency all my lines >79 col are split this way) and am wondering what other people's thoughts are.

Is this clear/nice to look at? Does this adhere to PEP 8?

Comment: It's clear to look at. Don't  know about PEP 8 conformance.

Comment: It's fine! 
I prefer to have longer lines ~100 characters, and if it's not enough to put some parameters on the same line as `(` and some on the next, then the function perhaps takes too many parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [doc](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) on PEP8 it is. Breaking up the function declaration to multi-line is fine as long as the indent level is 4 spaces.

> Continuation lines should align wrapped elements either vertically
>   using Python's implicit line joining inside parentheses, brackets and
>   braces, or using a hanging indent [7]. When using a hanging indent the
>   following should be considered; there should be no arguments on the
>   first line and further indentation should be used to clearly
>   distinguish itself as a continuation line.
>
> Yes:
>
> ```
> # Aligned with opening delimiter. 
> foo = long_function_name(var_one, var_two,
>                      var_three, var_four)
>
> # More indentation included to distinguish this from the rest. 
> def long_function_name(
>     var_one, var_two, var_three,
>     var_four):
> print(var_one)
>
> # Hanging indents should add a level. 
> foo = long_function_name(
> var_one, var_two,
> var_three, var_four)
> ```

As a side note if you find your function signature to be getting long due to the number of arguments, consider breaking up your function to more atomic units (*therefore adhering to clean code principles*).

Comment: thanks! Any comments about my edit w/ the  **if** statement?
I tend to be somewhat verbose in parameter names, so even if I just have 2-3 parameters I tend to cross the 79 col limit (maybe that is something I need to change?)

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#multiline-if-statements give that a read @wrwlf

Comment: On a side note, sometimes I personally like to place long boolean expression on their own line for clarity. i.e. `is_long_boolean = expression1 and expression2 and expression 3`. Then use it like so `if is_long_boolean`.

Comment: I think I will consider doing the same for long boolean expressions, thank you!